# Julia & Functions - NoMethodError

Tags: julia

I'm not understanding why the following snippet of code is returning a NoMethodError in Julia

```
using Calculus

nx = 101
nt = 101
dx = 2*pi / (nx - 1)
nu = 0.07
dt = dx*nu

function init(x, nu, t)
    phi = exp( -x^2 / 4.0*nu ) + exp( -(x - 2.0*pi)^2 / 4.0*nu )

    dphi_dx = derivative(phi)

    u = ( 2.0*nu /phi )*dphi_dx + 4.0

    return u
end

x = range(0.0,stop=2*pi,length=nx)
t = 0.0

u = [init(x0,nu,t) for x0 in x]
```

My aim here is to populate the elements of an array named u with values as calculated by my function init.  The u array should have nx elements with u calculated at every x value in the range between 0.0 and 2*pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time please also post the error message and take a detailed at it before, so you can try to spot the mistake by yourself.

I don't really know the `Calculus` package but it seems you are using it wrong. Your `phi` is a number and not a function. You can't take a derivative from just a single number. Change it to

```
phi = x -> exp( -x^2 / 4.0*nu ) + exp( -(x - 2.0*pi)^2 / 4.0*nu )
```

an then call the `phi` and `derivative` at argument `x`, so `phi(x)` and `derivative(phi,x)` or `dphi_x(x)`. As I don't know much about the `Calculus` package you should take a look at its documentation again to verify that the derivative command is doing exactly what you want like that.

Little extra: there are also element-wise operations in Julia (similar to Matlab for example) that apply functions to the whole array. Instead of `[init(x0,nu,t) for x0 in x]`, you can also write `init.(x,nu,t)`.

Comment: You're right, the issue I was having was due to improperly using the derivative function in the Calculus package.  Changing my definitions for phi and dphi_dx to `phi(x) = exp( -x^2 / 4.0*nu ) + exp( -(x - 2.0*pi)^2 / 4.0*nu )` and `dphi_dx = derivative(phi)` seems to resolve the issue, so that when I pass a value x0 to the function init, u is evaluated correctly. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.